# How to modify local group policy setting programatically

Tags: group-policy

I am looking for a way to programatically change the value of a group policy setting without having to reboot a machine or install any additional components on it

Looking for a solution for Windows 2003, 2008, machines are part of the domain

The value is under Administrative Templates\Network\QoS Packet Scheduler, Limit outstanding packets

Tried the following:

- Change registry directly - this doesn't work, as the value is actually stored in registry.pol file and is propagated from there to the registry
- Used WMI - WMI objects that are representing the registry are read only, value is not modified

One option that seems to work is to modify the registry.pol file under C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine, however this seems problematic, I will have to parse this file manually.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a .NET library to assist with this problem. You can read about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130408094308/http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows). It is open and source and you can get code and binaries [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100721100443/http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2010/01/15/updated-lgpo-utility-sources.aspx). Once you know the registry values that are relevant you can make the necessary changes to them using this library and it will save them into the registry.pol file.

Comment: Do you know how can I use this library in pure C? because my project compiled with `./configure && make && make install` under minGW. Thanks

Comment: I based my .NET library around this C solution here: http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/03/porgramatically-setting-and-applying.html
The source for my .NET solution is freely available at the link above, in case that helps.

Comment: @MartinEden the bitbucket link is broken do you have anywhere else?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid not. Looks like I've lost that code have no backups now that BitBucket has discontinued Mercurial support. :( Sorry, that was careless of me - I only ever worked on it on my work computer, and I've left that job, so I don't have a copy on my home computer. It was quite a small library - my only suggestion is that you read the blog post and try and recreate it a similar solution. Sorry again.

Comment: Both stale links in the post (and the source code for the library) were archived by the WayBackMachine so I updated the links.

Answer (score 0):

use this link
:)

https://web.archive.org/web/20100721100443/http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2010/01/15/updated-lgpo-utility-sources.aspx

you can use this Project For modify GPO on local System.
not change Direct Registry!!!!

```
HRESULT hr;
IGroupPolicyObject* pLGPO;
HKEY machine_key, dsrkey;

const IID my_IID_IGroupPolicyObject =
{ 0xea502723, 0xa23d, 0x11d1, { 0xa7, 0xd3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xe3 } };
const IID my_CLSID_GroupPolicyObject =
{ 0xea502722, 0xa23d, 0x11d1, { 0xa7, 0xd3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xe3 } };
GUID ext_guid = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;
// This next one can be any GUID you want
GUID snap_guid = { 0x3d271cfc, 0x2bc6, 0x4ac2, { 0xb6, 0x33, 0x3b, 0xdf, 0xf5, 0xbd, 0xab, 0x2a } };

// Create an instance of the IGroupPolicyObject class
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
CoCreateInstance(my_CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    my_IID_IGroupPolicyObject, (LPVOID*)&pLGPO);

// We need the machine LGPO (if C++, no need to go through the lpVtbl table)
hr = pLGPO->OpenLocalMachineGPO( GPO_OPEN_LOAD_REGISTRY);
hr = pLGPO->GetRegistryKey( GPO_SECTION_MACHINE, &machine_key);
//hr = pLGPO->GetRegistryKey(GPO_SECTION_USER, &machine_key);

// The disable System Restore is a DWORD value of Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Settings
LSTATUS sdf = RegCreateKeyEx(machine_key, L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DeviceInstall\\Settings",
    0, NULL, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, NULL, &dsrkey, NULL);

// Create the value
LSTATUS ds = RegSetKeyValue(dsrkey, NULL, KeyValue, REG_DWORD, &KeyData, sizeof(KeyData));
RegCloseKey(dsrkey);

// Apply policy and free resources
//pLGPO->Save( TRUE, TRUE, &ext_guid, &snap_guid);
GUID RegistryId = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;
GUID ThisAdminToolGuid =
    /*{ CLSID_PolicySnapinUser/* */
{
    0x0F6B957E,
    0x509E,
    0x11D1,
    { 0xA7, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xE3 }
};
     
LSTATUS rStatus = RegCloseKey(machine_key);
//
// Write the GPO back to the directory
//
hr = pLGPO->Save(
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    &RegistryId,
    &ThisAdminToolGuid);

RegCloseKey(machine_key);
pLGPO->Release();
```