# Java - Uncloseable Full Screen

Tags: java

I want to make a CyberCafe client which is initially run in full screen and disables Alt+Tab, Window key+Tab and Ctrl+Alt+Del intentionally, but enable it back when the right authorization is given (example: a right user/pass is given or a time based authorization is given).

I have read many times that disabling Ctrl+Alt+Del is only doable using JNI and is not recommended but I really need to disable these only when in full screen.

I hope anyone can help.

Comment: You can't.  The OS traps Ctrl+Alt+Del before your program ever sees it (for quite sensible security reasons), and you can't switch that off in a Java program.

Comment: I have seen some java programs doing it.. that is why I want to know how it could be done..

Comment: It might be possible to implement this through interaction with [custom windows policies](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/customize-ctrlaltdel-screen-windows-7-group-policy). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137215/how-to-modify-local-group-policy-setting-programatically) may be helpful. However most likely the process will require some manual setup from system's administrator.

Comment: @KaryuuOuji if you have an example you can either contact the author or disassemble it and find out how they are doing it. (However disassembling might be a violation of EULA).

Comment: @user3707125 that is why I am asking it here...